# Limit a user to edit AND view only a specific content type?

Tags: users, nodes

I have a role dedicated to creating and/or editing a specific content type.  It is the only activity to be allowed for this role.

I have set up login destinations module to go to the content overview and it pretty much works fine.  Users can only edit the allowed content type and when they add content, they immediately get the content type they are allowed to use.

The issue is that I want the user in this role to ONLY see the content type they are allowed to modify.  Currently, it lists all the nodes, which will be confusing for the folks using this role.

Any ideas on a way to use the content overview screen and limit the nodes viewable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use Views?

Answer (score 1):

If you have to control the list of content where they go to find content to edit, then you should use [VIEWS](https://drupal.org/project/views) & make list of only those content which they have permission to edit. Set a page for that list & navigate them there. It's pretty easy..

But if you want to restrict full content type for viewing then you can use [Content Access](https://drupal.org/project/content_access) module for that.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried a view first and my issue was that I'd have to create and "Add Content" button of some sort.  Since I was so close with the built-in content overview, it seemed the logical choice.  I'm trying to keep the system relatively simple to maintain with a minimum of custom PHP.

Comment: @KCL - You can make a view & show it on dashboard. Set their navigation to the dashboard when they login. You will similar experience of content overview if you use dashboard & view together.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Access Control Lists](https://drupal.org/project/acl).

> The ACL module, short for **Access Control Lists**, is an API for other modules to create lists of users and give them access to nodes. It has no UI of its own and will not do anything by itself; install this module only if some other module tells you to.

Comment: This answer is of little help for the OP, since you do not explain *why* and *how* to use ACL.  Also, the ACL module has no user interface and is only intended to be used as a helper module for other modules, so by itself, it will do nothing. It also resolves to *users*, not *roles* as requested by the OP.

Comment: How to write a good answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7656

Answer (score 0):

Ok, depending on how many roles you have & how many content types they are allowed to use you can simply create ::

The content types to fit each particular role so when each ROLE TYPE adds content they could only see their Corresponding CONTENT TYPE nodes respectively..

this can be done using::

Permissions
Roles
Content type

It will leave a messy back end if you have tons of roles & content types but if their is only 2-3 it should be the easiest & simplest way..!